# C++ Not reading in values into array from text file

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been trying to read in values from a text file into 2 arrays, however I end up with nothing inside my `names` and `scores` arrays. Here's what I have:

```
const int size = 6;
int names[size] = { 0 };
int scores[size] = { 0 };
int name;
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("input.txt"); //opens up textfile

inputFile >> name;
while (!inputFile.eof()){
    inputFile >> names[x] >> scores[x];
    cout << names[x] << scores[x];
    x++;
}
```

input.txt

```
6
Alice 50
Bob 100
Cathryn 75
Don 90
Emily 80
Flora 60
George 95
```

`name` is picking up a value of 6, but `names` and `scores` are picking up nothing. Any ideas about what's wrong?

Comment: have you initialized x? like x = 0?

Comment: Show us the declaration for your `names` and `scores` array.

Comment: Try `cout << inputFile` instead and see if the file is actually being read.

Comment: and now where is size? :-)

Comment: Is `size` a constant?

Comment: Also try printing the length of the two arrays to be sure they are not size 1 or size 0. Add `-Wall` to your compile command to be sure you are getting all warnings that you might be missing.

Comment: @gragas, I'm using Visual Studio and I can see there's an array of size 6 being created for both

Comment: `while (!eof())` is always the wrong way to condition your input. Do `while (inputFile >> names[x] >> scores[x])`.

Comment: Aside: this demonstrates a very good reason to do proper error checking, even if you're controlling the input so that there should be no errors -- it makes it that much easier to debug mistakes! If you had known that the stream was going `bad` rather than `eof`, you might have caught onto your mistake. I think 90% of mysterious I/O behavior can be chalked up to a stream going bad unnoticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're program doesn't work because you accidentally initialized `names` as an array type `int`, instead of type `std::string`. This breaks the whole line `inputFile >> names[x] >> scores[x];`.

Silly mistake. Just make a data structure of `std::string`s called `names` and put stuff in it.

Comment: I'm so out of it... Thanks gragas!